# content of one div overlapping to another div

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

i have 4 divs these are

```
<div id="wrapper"><div id="AccWiseDate">Date</div><div id="AccWiseMemo">MemoMemoMemoMemoMemoMemo</div><div id="AccWiseDebit">Debit</div><div id="AccWiseCredit">Credit</div></div>
```

and my css code is

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
  width:100%;
  clear: both;
}

#AccWiseDate {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#AccWiseMemo {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#AccWiseDebit {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#AccWiseCredit {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

sometimes memo is much larger than width so it overlap to another div. and i need to hide the extra text. for more detail see the jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/WuZat/65/

what am i donig wrong. plz help thnks

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/WuZat/70/

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying AccWiseMemo as below as see if it help.

```
#AccWiseMemo {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: it works fine. but it ruins my formatting that means it streched the whole line out of screen. can you solve this. thanks

Comment: can you be more specific, it's unclear for me what result you want to gain, in[THIS jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WuZat/71/) it looks ok

Comment: actually i am using jquerymobile to make an android phonegap app. and i want to show some records in a row. i can use a table but i am using an li tag and one li tag contains these 4 divs and result shows in a row. byr using overflow i can manage overlapping but it streched means it took more size than device width because of memo text length. if i give memo text within its width then it have proper orientation. so i need to manage the length of that memo text , so that i can handle the records in properly visible row. so i think i need to cut the extra text after the given width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use css property.

```
#AccWiseMemo {
float: left;
width:25%;
text-align: left;
font-size: 15px;
word-break: break-all;}
```

Kindly replace your code with above and check.

Answer (score 0):

Use `word-wrap: break-word;`

```
#AccWiseDebit {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```